# Active record associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, rails-activerecord

Is it possible to build two scaffolds independently and then add active record associations to them from scratch? Finding it difficult to find a solution on line that does  it this way.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Scaffold simply "dumps" code into your project, you can/should edit it later. The templates scaffolding use, are not meant to create production apps, rather a jump start, specially for new developers.

If you want to re-run scaffold you can do so, and the generator will ask you to override files or not.

Comment: so I simply run the same scaffold command with the association included in it?

Comment: You mean included in the model? Yeah, but understand scaffolding has it's limits and you should/will have to edit the generated files. Don't override the model when you run the generator again.